# Syntax for explicitly referencing a column name

Tags: sql, palantir-foundry

I'm trying to make a join to a date table on a column called 'date'.
The issue I have is that the column name is the same as the table and it seems to be making a referencing to the table rather than the column (hence the yellow highlighting). I've found a workaround which is to rename the table - though does anyone know how to explicitly reference the column in the join rather than the table if they have the same name?
[image: Picture example]

Answer (score 3):

You can give aliases to the table/column and use that instead. Otherwise, you can use the table name before the column with a `.` as a separator, i.e., `TableName.date = date`.